# Get current playback time of background audio after navigating away and back to the page - UWP

Tags: c#, uwp

I am using MediaPlayer class to play audio with the background audio capability enabled in the manifest. I am using my own play/pause button to control the playback.

Everything works fine except when I navigate away from the page and come back, I lose the current playback progress of the background audio being played which is being displayed on a TextBlock.

How do I connect back to that background audio?? I can't seem to find a solution.

Thanks

Comment: Just keep a reference to the MediaPlayer that's playing the music somewhere (a static variable perhaps?) and then hook it back up the same way you did the first time.

Comment: Take a look at [Background media playback sample](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/master/Samples/BackgroundMediaPlayback)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Johnny and Vimal for the correct pointers. I am using the class below that always returns a single instance...it works!

```
public class PlaybackService
{
    private static PlaybackService instance;

    public static PlaybackService Instance
    {
        get
        {
            if (instance == null)
                instance = new PlaybackService();

            return instance;
        }
    }

    public MediaPlayer Player { get; private set; }

    public PlaybackService()
    {
        // Create the player instance
        Player = new MediaPlayer();

    }

}
```